# how does snapshot with (Events for metadata changes) differs than normal snapshot in cloud firestore?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

What is the main difference between using { includeMetadataChanges: true } in snapshot function and not using it at all, as I understood from docs it kind of more sensitive to change ?

```js
import { doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";

const unsub = onSnapshot(
  doc(db, "cities", "SF"), 
  { includeMetadataChanges: true }, 
  (doc) => {
    // ...
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you listen for values with `includeMetadataChanges: true`, your callback also gets invoked when only the [metadata of a snapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.SnapshotMetadata) has changed. Specifically this may happen when the client has verified that there were no changes on the server (so `fromCache` becomes true) or when local writes have been committed on the server (and so `hasPendingWrites` becomes false).

Without the flag, you'd not be notified of those changes, as they're not commonly shown in the UI of the app (although they definitely can be).

Comment: so even if there is no change then it will be triggered so my assumption is right then it is more sensitive to every thing.